# Formating T-SQL to return JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, subquery

I would like to use MS SQL Server to return my data as JSON and almost have the format correct but I am stuck.  I think that I need another subquery but I cannot seem to get the subquery to format correctly.

I've been using this blog post as my 'tutorial' ([XML_JSON](https://devjef.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/using-for-xml-to-create-arrays-json-and-javascript/)) which was quite helpful getting to where I am.  As you can see when you run my query the output is close to the desired format but I am not nesting 'Measure' correctly and I think I need another subquery to get it correct. However, it is not clear to me how to do the nesting...

Thanks!!

```
DECLARE  @tmp_nata TABLE


(FIPS varchar(max),
   Measure VARCHAR(max),
   HAP VARCHAR(max),
   Result float)


INSERT INTO @tmp_nata
  (FIPS, Measure, HAP, Result)
VALUES
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Benzene', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Lead', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Butadiene', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Acrolein', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'PAH', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Arsenic', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Chromium', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Diesel PM', 10.00),

  ('00001', 'NeuroNonCancer_HQ', 'Lead', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'Cum_AirToxicNonCancerNeuro', 'None', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'Cum_AirToxicNonCancerRespir', 'None', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'Cum_AirToxicCancer', 'None', 15.00),

  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Acrolein', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Formaldehyde', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Acetaldehyde', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Diesel PM', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Chromium', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Naphthalene', 10.00),

  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Benzene', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Butadiene', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'PAH', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Arsenic', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Chromium', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 15.00),

  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Benzene', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Lead', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Butadiene', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Acrolein', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'PAH', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Arsenic', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Chromium', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Diesel PM', 10.00),

  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Benzene', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Lead', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Butadiene', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Acrolein', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 275.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'PAH', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Arsenic', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Chromium', 275.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Diesel PM', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'NeuroNonCancer_HQ', 'Lead', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'Cum_AirToxicNonCancerNeuro', 'None', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'Cum_AirToxicNonCancerRespir', 'None', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'Cum_AirToxicCancer', 'None', 275.00),

  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Acrolein', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Formaldehyde', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Acetaldehyde', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Diesel PM', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Chromium', 75.00),
  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Naphthalene', 210.00),

  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Benzene', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Butadiene', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'PAH', 275.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Arsenic', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Chromium', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 215.00),

  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Benzene', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Lead', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Butadiene', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Acrolein', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 275.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'PAH', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Arsenic', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Chromium', 275.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Diesel PM', 210.00) 

SELECT * from @tmp_nata

  SELECT
  FIPS, 
    STUFF((SELECT
          (',"' + SUB.Measure + '":{"'+ SUB.HAP+ '":' + CAST(Result as varchar(max)) + '}')
           FROM @tmp_nata SUB
           WHERE SUB.FIPS = AT.FIPS
           ORDER BY SUB.FIPS, SUB.Measure, SUB.HAP ASC
           FOR XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 1, '')  AS JSON
FROM @tmp_nata AT
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY FIPS
```

The desired output is one JSON per FIPS and it would look like this for FIPS=00001:

```
{
    "EnvConcEstimate": {
        "Benzene": 10,
        "Lead": 125,
        "Butadiene": 15,
        "Acrolein": 10,
        "Naphthalene": 15,
        "Formaldehyde": 10,
        "PAH": 125,
        "Acetaldehyde": 15,
        "Arsenic": 10,
        "Chromium": 15,
        "Diesel PM": 10
    },
    "NeuroNonCancer_HQ": {
        "Lead": 125
    },
    "Cum_AirToxicNonCancerNeuro": {
        "None": 15
    },
    "Cum_AirToxicNonCancerRespir": {
        "None": 10
    },
    "Cum_AirToxicCancer": {
        "None": 15
    },
    "RespNonCancer_HQ": {
        "Acrolein": 10,
        "Formaldehyde": 125,
        "Acetaldehyde": 15,
        "Diesel PM": 10,
        "Chromium": 15,
        "Naphthalene": 10
    },
    "HealthRiskEstimate": {
        "Benzene": 125,
        "Butadiene": 15,
        "Formaldehyde": 10,
        "PAH": 15,
        "Acetaldehyde": 10,
        "Arsenic": 125,
        "Chromium": 125,
        "Naphthalene": 15
    },
    "HumanExpEstimate": {
        "Benzene": 10,
        "Lead": 125,
        "Butadiene": 15,
        "Acrolein": 10,
        "Naphthalene": 15,
        "Formaldehyde": 10,
        "PAH": 125,
        "Acetaldehyde": 15,
        "Arsenic": 10,
        "Chromium": 15,
        "Diesel PM": 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you need to do this in SQL rather than in the application layer?

Comment: I agree with @GarethD. There are libraries that allow you to take an entity and easily get the JSON representation. This would be far easier to deal with in my opinion.

Comment: Yes (since you asked).  I am actually using SQL Server to house my GIS (Geographic Information Systems) data and I need to process it extensively (not part of the question).  I then need to save spatially join the output of this query to additional GIS layers (via ArcMap), prior to giving it to others for a web application.

Comment: I'm agree with @GarethD totally, but it depends on some conditions (i.e: langs or techs used by app, app architecture, etc) and may be some times mining such this data with such these formats in database layer  be better or even be the only solution for problem, That's why I wrote the code which gives exactly what yo want, you can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JUST SOLVED YOUR PROBLEM**, I tried it without using `FOR XML PATH`, what I did create another table variable `with an extra field to build jason object` per each row, I inserted from main table to declared table and then built json object per each row by checking `PIPS` and `Measure`. anyone can execute below codes and check the result [HERE](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

---

*Schema:*

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_nata TABLE
(FIPS varchar(max),
   Measure VARCHAR(max),
   HAP VARCHAR(max),
   Result float)


INSERT INTO @tmp_nata
  (FIPS, Measure, HAP, Result)
VALUES
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Benzene', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Lead', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Butadiene', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Acrolein', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'PAH', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Arsenic', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Chromium', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Diesel PM', 10.00),

  ('00001', 'NeuroNonCancer_HQ', 'Lead', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'Cum_AirToxicNonCancerNeuro', 'None', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'Cum_AirToxicNonCancerRespir', 'None', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'Cum_AirToxicCancer', 'None', 15.00),

  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Acrolein', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Formaldehyde', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Acetaldehyde', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Diesel PM', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Chromium', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Naphthalene', 10.00),

  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Benzene', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Butadiene', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'PAH', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Arsenic', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Chromium', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 15.00),

  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Benzene', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Lead', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Butadiene', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Acrolein', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'PAH', 125.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Arsenic', 10.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Chromium', 15.00),
  ('00001', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Diesel PM', 10.00),

  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Benzene', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Lead', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Butadiene', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Acrolein', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 275.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'PAH', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Arsenic', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Chromium', 275.00),
  ('20000', 'EnvConcEstimate', 'Diesel PM', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'NeuroNonCancer_HQ', 'Lead', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'Cum_AirToxicNonCancerNeuro', 'None', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'Cum_AirToxicNonCancerRespir', 'None', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'Cum_AirToxicCancer', 'None', 275.00),

  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Acrolein', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Formaldehyde', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Acetaldehyde', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Diesel PM', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Chromium', 75.00),
  ('20000', 'RespNonCancer_HQ', 'Naphthalene', 210.00),

  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Benzene', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Butadiene', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'PAH', 275.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Arsenic', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Chromium', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'HealthRiskEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 215.00),

  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Benzene', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Lead', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Butadiene', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Acrolein', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Naphthalene', 275.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Formaldehyde', 210.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'PAH', 2125.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Acetaldehyde', 215.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Arsenic', 250.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Chromium', 275.00),
  ('20000', 'HumanExpEstimate', 'Diesel PM', 210.00)
```

---

*Query:*

```
DECLARE
    @FIPS VARCHAR(50),
    @Measure VARCHAR(50),
    @Vals VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @FIPS ='';
SET @Measure ='';
SET @Vals ='';

DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    FIPS VARCHAR(50),
    Measure VARCHAR(50),
    HAP VARCHAR(50),
    Result FLOAT,
    Vals VARCHAR(MAX)
 ); 

INSERT @t(FIPS,Measure,HAP,Result)
SELECT FIPS,Measure,HAP,Result FROM tmp_nata
ORDER BY FIPS,Measure,HAP;


UPDATE @t 
SET @Vals = Vals =
    CASE @FIPS
         WHEN FIPS THEN
                   CASE @Measure
                        WHEN Measure THEN 
                                     @Vals +', "'+ HAP + '":'+cast(Result as varchar(100))
                        ELSE @Vals +'}, "'+Measure+'": {"'+ HAP + '":'+cast(Result as varchar(100))
                   END
         ELSE  '{ "'+Measure+'": {'+' "'+ HAP + '":'+cast(Result as varchar(100))
         END,
    @FIPS=FIPS, 
    @Measure = Measure;



SELECT DISTINCT FIPS, Vals= MAX(Vals)+'}}'
FROM @t
GROUP BY FIPS
ORDER BY FIPS;
```

---

*Output:*

```
FIPS    Vals
00001   { "EnvConcEstimate": { "Benzene":10, "Lead":125, "Butadiene":15, "Acrolein":10, "Naphthalene":15, "Formaldehyde":10, "PAH":125, "Acetaldehyde":15, "Arsenic":10, "Chromium":15, "Diesel PM":10}, "NeuroNonCancer_HQ": {"Lead":125}, "Cum_AirToxicNonCancerNeuro": {"None":15}, "Cum_AirToxicNonCancerRespir": {"None":10}, "Cum_AirToxicCancer": {"None":15}, "RespNonCancer_HQ": {"Acrolein":10, "Formaldehyde":125, "Acetaldehyde":15, "Diesel PM":10, "Chromium":15, "Naphthalene":10}, "HealthRiskEstimate": {"Benzene":125, "Butadiene":15, "Formaldehyde":10, "PAH":15, "Acetaldehyde":10, "Arsenic":125, "Chromium":125, "Naphthalene":15}, "HumanExpEstimate": {"Benzene":10, "Lead":125, "Butadiene":15, "Acrolein":10, "Naphthalene":15, "Formaldehyde":10, "PAH":125, "Acetaldehyde":15, "Arsenic":10, "Chromium":15, "Diesel PM":10}}
20000   { "EnvConcEstimate": { "Benzene":210, "Lead":2125, "Butadiene":215, "Acrolein":250, "Naphthalene":275, "Formaldehyde":210, "PAH":2125, "Acetaldehyde":215, "Arsenic":250, "Chromium":275, "Diesel PM":210}, "NeuroNonCancer_HQ": {"Lead":2125}, "Cum_AirToxicNonCancerNeuro": {"None":215}, "Cum_AirToxicNonCancerRespir": {"None":250}, "Cum_AirToxicCancer": {"None":275}, "RespNonCancer_HQ": {"Acrolein":210, "Formaldehyde":2125, "Acetaldehyde":215, "Diesel PM":250, "Chromium":75, "Naphthalene":210}, "HealthRiskEstimate": {"Benzene":2125, "Butadiene":215, "Formaldehyde":250, "PAH":275, "Acetaldehyde":210, "Arsenic":2125, "Chromium":2125, "Naphthalene":215}, "HumanExpEstimate": {"Benzene":210, "Lead":2125, "Butadiene":215, "Acrolein":250, "Naphthalene":275, "Formaldehyde":210, "PAH":2125, "Acetaldehyde":215, "Arsenic":250, "Chromium":275, "Diesel PM":210}}
```

Comment: This was close but the nesting was not proper when the original table was unsorted.  I changed it for you.   I awarded you the answer because I am using ESRI's ArcMap and arcpy to query a database and your answer will work while the other does not.

Comment: great, glad to see your problem has solved, I really did effort on this answer to not use "for xml path" to be an idea for other sql suported rdbmss,  thanks for the award and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply your logic twice, first for haps and result and then for measure. You can do it by `CTE` for example:

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT
  FIPS, '"' + Measure +'":{'+
    STUFF((SELECT
          (',"' + SUB.HAP + '":'+CAST(Result AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '')
           FROM t SUB
           WHERE SUB.FIPS = AT.FIPS AND SUB.Measure = AT.Measure
           ORDER BY SUB.Measure, SUB.HAP
           FOR XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 1, '') + '}' AS JSON
FROM t AT
GROUP BY FIPS, Measure)

SELECT FIPS, 
'{' + STUFF((SELECT
          (',' + JSON)
           FROM cte SUB
           WHERE SUB.FIPS = AT.FIPS
           ORDER BY SUB.FIPS
           FOR XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 1, '') + '}' AS JSON
           FROM cte AS AT
GROUP BY FIPS
```

Sample output:

```
00001   {"EnvConcEstimate":{"Benzene":10,"Lead":125},"NeuroNonCancer_HQ":{"Lead":125}}
20000   {"Cum_AirToxicCancer":{"None":275},"Cum_AirToxicNonCancerNeuro":{"None":215},"Cum_AirToxicNonCancerRespir":{"None":250},"EnvConcEstimate":{"Benzene":210,"Lead":2125},"NeuroNonCancer_HQ":{"Lead":2125}}
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c73e4/13

Comment: The solution does work within MS SQL but I did not award you the answer because for some reason it will not work within my system.  I am using ESRI's ArcMap and arcpy to query a database and I think it will not let me use a CTE.  The code in the answer below did work in my system.